# Flask form submit: request.stream.read() contais data, but request.form doesn't

Tags: flask, form-submit

I'm trying to submit a simpliest form ever:

```
<form class="form-search" action='/render' method="POST">
    <input name='test' type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

(that's Bootstrap, and I've just taken a raw example from its site)

...to a simpliest handler ever:

```
@app.route('/render', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def render():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.stream.read()
        print request.data
        print request.form
    return 'ok'
```

And that's what I've got:

```
>> test=1
>> 
>> ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

I'm really confused: that seems to be so simple. I've seen a couple of the same-looking problems - the issue was missing input 'name' attribute, but that seems to be the different case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I've figured it out. Looks like when you do `request.stream.read()`, it empties your `request.form` dictionary.